# Why must a tensor with real components be symmetric to have (guarantee) real eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

Consider a rank-2 tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$. We say it has an eigenvalue $a$ if $T_{\mu \nu} v^\nu = a \eta_{\mu \sigma} v^\sigma$. All $T_{\mu \nu}$ and $v^\sigma$ are real.

I reason that
$$
T_{\mu \nu} v^\nu = a \eta_{\mu \sigma} v^\sigma ,\\
T_{\mu \nu} v^\nu v^\mu = a \eta_{\mu \sigma} v^\sigma v^\mu ,\\
T_{\mu \nu} v^\mu v^\nu = a \eta_{\mu \sigma} v^\mu v^\sigma ,\\
T_{\mu \nu} v^\mu v^\nu = a v_\sigma v^\sigma ,\\
$$
where clearly the contractions $T_{\mu \nu} v^\mu v^\nu$ and $v_\sigma v^\sigma$ are real, thus $a$ must be real.

So, as far as I can tell, the requirement of being symmetric is superfluous. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Who says that it must be symmetric?

Comment: @HansLundmark Well I’d agree with that, but my lecture stipulated *symmetric* tensor in the problem sheet!

Comment: It doesn't have to be symmetric to have real eigenvalues. But if it is symmetric it will _always_ have only real eigenvalues. Presumably that's what you're asked to show. Not all rank-2 tensors have real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Arthur What’s wrong with my above proof then?

Comment: BTW, when I say "to have", I mean to "to guarantee", of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that a real eigenvector $v$ exists. And clearly, if an eigenvector with real entries exists, and the entries of $T$ are real, then the corresponding eigenvalue must be real. This is what you have shown.

As a concrete counterexample, consider the antisymmetric
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then which vector $v$ would satisfy
$$
T_{\mu \nu} v^\nu = a \eta_{\mu \sigma} v^\sigma
$$
for some $a$? That is, in fact, the two vectors $[1, \pm i]^T$ with eigenvalues $a = \mp i$ (I might have the sign wrong).

On the other hand, if $T$ is a symmetric tensor, then all eigenvalues are necessarily real and they all have real eigenvectors. That's partly why symmetry is such an important property.

Comment: Ah yes. I was making the assumption that all vectors are real, since I am working in Minkowski space here. How do you prove this without the assumption the eigenvectors are real?

Comment: @Noldorin The standard linear algebra proof (using (1,1)-tensors, commonly referred to as matrices) goes like this: Conjugate transpose both sides of the equality $v^*Tv = v^*av$ and use $T^* = T$ and $v^*v\neq 0$ to conclude $a=\bar a$. Presumably you can do something similar here, although you would need to establish some conjugation trickery like $\eta_{\mu\sigma}v^\mu = \overline{v_\sigma}$ to make sure $v^\sigma v_\sigma\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.